# Find the Nth term in a sequence in C++

Tags: c++, algorithm, math, matrix, recurrence

I have found a problem in which you are given this type of sequence:

you have

```
  the first K terms : a1, a2, ... , ak; 
           K coefficients : b1, b2, ... , bk
```

and a recurrence:

```
S(i) = b1*S(i-K) + b2*S(i-K+1) + ... + bk*S(i-1).
```

I have to find out the Nth term.

I believe this problem can be solved with fast matrix exponentiation but I am having hard time discovering the matrices I have to use. I am trying to write the problem in C++. Can anyone give me some hints about how should I treat this type of problem?

Comment: This is at least possible for a subset of these kinds of sequences. Namely, the nth Fibonacci number can be found [using matrices](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number#Matrix_form). I don't know how well it generalizes, however.

Answer (score 1):

As a shameless self-promotion, I coded up [a program to solve linear recurrences using matrix multiplication](http://keithschwarz.com/interesting/code/?dir=recurrence).  The comments at the top of the file describe what the matrix you want to form is, as well as how to use the repeated squaring algorithm to efficiently compute the nth term of the recurrence.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer...I have one question though matrix.hh is a library that yout created or you can find on the internet?

Comment: @user2128547- It's a library I created.  It's available online here: http://keithschwarz.com/interesting/code/?dir=matrix